# Is it possible to recognise light patterns on iOS?

Tags: ios, image-processing, augmented-reality, image-recognition, metaio

Is it possible to recognise light patterns on iOS?

Is there a native iOS SDK to do so?

**Use case:**
Detect light patterns (e.g. on / off) using smartphone camera

**Background information**:
Apple has [acquired](http://techcrunch.com/2015/05/28/apple-metaio/) last year **Metaio** so I presume at some point we will have such SDK, but for now I presume that the best way to achieve this is by using third party SDK or using image capturing and processing the image (if the images are simple enough so that a simple algorithm can be applied).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "light patterns"?

Comment: Why do you need a SDK from an augmented reality company to detect light patterns? Please explain what you want to do and what you understand by "light patterns"

Comment: I mean colours of lights and the time interval between them.. I guess I could simply try to detect a specific RGB colour in an image captured using the video feed.. or camera..

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at Kudan AR. https://www.kudan.eu/

They currently offer a SDK for iOS, not yet for Android. Their tracking quality is phenomenally good. But, I do not know if it is appropriate to your goals. It would be best if you talk to them and ask if their tracking would fit your needs.